# How can I format number in plotly Indicator?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm now plotting `go.Indicator` and face a problem with the number format. Specifically, my code is as below

```
fig.add_trace(
            go.Indicator(
                mode = "delta",
                value = df[df.columns[2]].values[-1],
                domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 1},
                delta = {"reference": df[df.columns[2]].values[-13], 
                         "valueformat": "f",
                         "suffix": "%"},
                ),
                    row = 2,
                    col = 1
                    
                )
```

And the figure now like:

[image: go.Indicator]

the raw number is also equal 0.999717. However, I would like to show only `0.99` instead. I have tried to change the `"valueformat" = ".2f" or "2f` but it even makes a longer number.
How can I change the `"valueformat"`?

Answer (score 0):

Plotly uses the d3-format specified [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/tree/v1.4.5#d3-format). To get 2 decimal places, you can try `"valueformat": ".2"`, but in your specific case -0.999 would be rounded to -1, so you might want 3 decimal places.

Here is a simple example where the raw number is -0.98717, but we make the precision 2 decimal places so it shows -0.99:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Indicator(
        mode = "delta",
        value = -0.98717,
        delta = {"reference": 0.0, 
                    "valueformat": ".2",
                    "suffix": "%"},
        ),
    )

fig.show()
```

[image]